# Is Boost.Preprocessor self-contained?

Tags: boost-preprocessor

I'm thinking about using `Boost.Preprocessor` in some project, but I don't want to make the entire Boost library a dependency.

Can I just copy it alone and get away with this? Otherwise, what are its dependencies?

Answer (score 4):

## New Answer

I just got `bcp` working:

`./bcp --list preprocessor --boost=/usr/local/include/boost_1_45_0/ | grep -v preprocessor`

> no errors detected

w/o the grep I get something like:

> boost/preprocessor.hpp
>   boost/preprocessor/arithmetic.hpp
>   boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/add.hpp
>   boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/dec.hpp
>   boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/detail/div_base.hpp
>   boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/div.hpp
>   boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/inc.hpp
>   boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/mod.hpp
>   boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/mul.hpp
>   boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/sub.hpp

---

## Original answer

Try using the boost `bcp` utility to copy it

I did a quick `grep -R "include" /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/* | grep -v preprocessor` and didn't come up with any matches. I could have sworn that config was needed.

Edit (my grep-ful is weak =/)
`grep -rh "include" /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/* | grep -v preprocessor | sort |uniq`

> #    error BOOST_PP_ERROR:  no indirect file to include
>    #        include BOOST_PP_FILENAME_1
>    #    include BOOST_PP_FILENAME_1
>    #        include BOOST_PP_FILENAME_2
>    #    include BOOST_PP_FILENAME_2
>    #        include BOOST_PP_FILENAME_3
>    #    include BOOST_PP_FILENAME_3
>    #        include BOOST_PP_FILENAME_4
>    #    include BOOST_PP_FILENAME_4
>    #        include BOOST_PP_FILENAME_5
>    #    include BOOST_PP_FILENAME_5
>    # include BOOST_PP_INDIRECT_SELF

`grep -rhE "define\\s+BOOST_PP_FILENAME" /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/* | sort |uniq`

> #    define BOOST_PP_FILENAME_1 BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ELEM(2, BOOST_PP_ITERATION_PARAMS_1)
>    #    define BOOST_PP_FILENAME_2 BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ELEM(2, BOOST_PP_ITERATION_PARAMS_2)
>    #    define BOOST_PP_FILENAME_3 BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ELEM(2, BOOST_PP_ITERATION_PARAMS_3)
>    #    define BOOST_PP_FILENAME_4 BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ELEM(2, BOOST_PP_ITERATION_PARAMS_4)
>    #    define BOOST_PP_FILENAME_5 BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ELEM(2, BOOST_PP_ITERATION_PARAMS_5)

BOOST_PP_ITERATION_PARAMS_# don't seem to be `#defined` anywhere. Strangely enough, they are `#undef`ed in ./detail/iter/forward#.hpp so I'm probably missing some nested macro or other...

Comment: Whew, at least compilers agree on preprocessor implementation.

Comment: Your test is flawed. In front of each match it prints, grep will print the name of the file it found the match in. That will include "preprocessor" from the file-name prefix. Use the `-h` option to omit that.

Comment: On ubuntu this worked for me `mkdir pp; bcp preprocessor --boost=/usr/include/  pp/`

Answer (score 0):

As stated at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/ , Preprocessor is a header only library. No run time library needed.

Comment: This still doesn't mean it doesn't have dependencies on other (header-only) parts of boost.